# how to write a SED script to replace the version code present in a file based on user input using Regex

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed

I am taking the version code from user input and trying to replace the existing version code with the new one.

The file which contains version code is named `"Version.gradle"`, it contains

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.service_app"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

I am able to get the version from user, but I don not know how to replace the new version code with exiting one. I am using the below pattern to fetch the existing version code.

```
echo "Enter versionCode"
read versionCode
replacement=$(sed 'versionCode=\"(\\d+)\"' Version.gradle)
replacement=${versionCode}
sed "s/PATTERN/$replacement/g" Version.gradle
```

Current Output:

```
command : sed e version.sed
Enter versionCode
2
sed: -e expression #1, char 22: expected newer version of sed
sed: can't read Version.gradle: Permission denied
```

Expected Output:

In version.gradle file, 2 should replace the already existing version code.

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for sharing the code as your efforts here(keep it up), could you please also share sample of input and sample of expected output in your question and let us know then, to give a clear picture of requirement.

Comment: Please enter samples in form of text in your question NOT in images  please.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have edited my post to contain output. Please let me know if I am doing the right way, I am new to SED and I am not aware of any commands. Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: You seem not to have access to the file. First, make sure you have write access to the file.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you have write access to the file.

Then, you may use

```
sed -i "s/\(versionCode[[:space:]]*\)[0-9]*/\\1${versionCode}/" file
```

Using FreeBSD sed:

```
sed -i '' "s/\(versionCode[[:space:]]*\)[0-9]*/\\1${versionCode}/" file
```

**POSIX BRE pattern & replacement details**

- `\(versionCode[[:space:]]*\)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `versionCode` - a literal word
  - `[[:space:]]*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `[0-9]*` - 0 or more digits
- `\1` - Group 1 placeholder, it puts back the value captured in Group 1 back into the resulting string
- `${versionCode}` - the `versionCode` contents (note the double quotes surrounding the command, they enable variable expansion).

See the [online `sed` Linux demo](https://ideone.com/fT4qXD):

```
test=' defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.service_app"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}'
echo "Enter versionCode"
read versionCode
echo "$versionCode"
sed "s/\(versionCode[[:space:]]*\)[0-9]*/\1${versionCode}/" <<< "$test"
```